# Autodesk Forge Extension

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, forge

So I am following this tutorial to extend the autodesk forge viewer. I have compelted all of the steps and no button is showing, I assume this is due to an error with the loading.

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/extension-skeleton-toolbar-docking-panel

I have also tried this tutorial, with the same issue:

http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/viewer/extensions/selection?id=conclusion

My issue is I am not getting an error, the extension just isn't showing... does anyone know why?

I'm assuming theres an error in either the viewer or the index.

Below is my code: (index & forge viewer)

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Autodesk Forge Tutorial</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!-- Common packages: jQuery, Bootstrap, jsTree -->
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/MyAwesomeExtension.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />
    <!-- Autodesk Forge Viewer files -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/style.min.css?v=v6.0" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=v6.0"></script>
    <!-- this project files -->
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/ForgeTree.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ForgeViewer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Fixed navbar by Bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/ -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav left">
                <li>
                    <a href="http://developer.autodesk.com" target="_blank">
                        <img alt="Autodesk Forge" src="//developer.static.autodesk.com/images/logo_forge-2-line.png" height="20">
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- End of navbar -->
    <div class="container-fluid fill">
        <div class="row fill">
            <div class="col-sm-4 fill">
                <div class="panel panel-default fill">
                    <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="tooltip">
                        Buckets &amp; Objects
                        <span id="refreshBuckets" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" style="cursor: pointer"></span>
                        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info" style="float: right" id="showFormCreateBucket" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createBucketModal">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span> New bucket
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="appBuckets">
                        tree here
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 fill">
                <div id="forgeViewer"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form id="uploadFile" method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input id="hiddenUploadField" type="file" name="theFile" style="visibility:hidden" />
    </form>
    <!-- Modal Create Bucket -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="createBucketModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Cancel">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Create new bucket</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="text" id="newBucketKey" class="form-control"> For demonstration purposes, objects (files) are
                    NOT automatically translated. After you upload, right click on
                    the object and select "Translate".
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="createNewBucket">Go ahead, create the bucket</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

ForgeViewer.js:

```
var viewerApp;

function launchViewer(urn) {
    var options = {
        env: 'AutodeskProduction',
        getAccessToken: getForgeToken
    };
    var documentId = 'urn:' + urn;
    Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function onInitialized() {
        viewerApp = new Autodesk.Viewing.ViewingApplication('forgeViewer');
        viewerApp.registerViewer(viewerApp.k3D, Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D, { extensions: ['MyAwesomeExtension'] });
        viewerApp.loadDocument(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
    });
}

function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {
    // We could still make use of Document.getSubItemsWithProperties()
    // However, when using a ViewingApplication, we have access to the **bubble** attribute,
    // which references the root node of a graph that wraps each object from the Manifest JSON.
    var viewables = viewerApp.bubble.search({ 'type': 'geometry' });
    if (viewables.length === 0) {
        console.error('Document contains no viewables.');
        return;
    }

    // Choose any of the available viewables
    viewerApp.selectItem(viewables[0].data, onItemLoadSuccess, onItemLoadFail);
}

function onDocumentLoadFailure(viewerErrorCode) {
    console.error('onDocumentLoadFailure() - errorCode:' + viewerErrorCode);
}

function onItemLoadSuccess(viewer, item) {
    // item loaded, any custom action?
}

function onItemLoadFail(errorCode) {
    console.error('onItemLoadFail() - errorCode:' + errorCode);
}

function getForgeToken(callback) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/api/forge/oauth/token',
        success: function (res) {
            callback(res.access_token, res.expires_in)
        }
    });
}
```

MyAwesomeExtension.js:

```
// *******************************************
// My Awesome Extension
// *******************************************
function MyAwesomeExtension(viewer, options) {
    Autodesk.Viewing.Extension.call(this, viewer, options);
    this.panel = null;
}

MyAwesomeExtension.prototype = Object.create(Autodesk.Viewing.Extension.prototype);
MyAwesomeExtension.prototype.constructor = MyAwesomeExtension;

MyAwesomeExtension.prototype.load = function () {
    if (this.viewer.toolbar) {
        // Toolbar is already available, create the UI
        this.createUI();
    } else {
        // Toolbar hasn't been created yet, wait until we get notification of its creation
        this.onToolbarCreatedBinded = this.onToolbarCreated.bind(this);
        this.viewer.addEventListener(av.TOOLBAR_CREATED_EVENT, this.onToolbarCreatedBinded);
    }
    return true;
};

MyAwesomeExtension.prototype.onToolbarCreated = function () {
    this.viewer.removeEventListener(av.TOOLBAR_CREATED_EVENT, this.onToolbarCreatedBinded);
    this.onToolbarCreatedBinded = null;
    this.createUI();
};

MyAwesomeExtension.prototype.createUI = function () {
    var viewer = this.viewer;
    var panel = this.panel;

    // button to show the docking panel
    var toolbarButtonShowDockingPanel = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Button('showMyAwesomePanel');
    toolbarButtonShowDockingPanel.onClick = function (e) {
        // if null, create it
        if (panel == null) {
            panel = new MyAwesomePanel(viewer, viewer.container,
                'awesomeExtensionPanel', 'My Awesome Extension');
        }
        // show/hide docking panel
        panel.setVisible(!panel.isVisible());
    };
    // myAwesomeToolbarButton CSS class should be defined on your .css file
    // you may include icons, below is a sample class:
    /* 
    .myAwesomeToolbarButton {
        background-image: url(/img/myAwesomeIcon.png);
        background-size: 24px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
    }*/
    toolbarButtonShowDockingPanel.addClass('myAwesomeToolbarButton');
    toolbarButtonShowDockingPanel.setToolTip('My Awesome extension');

    // SubToolbar
    this.subToolbar = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.ControlGroup('MyAwesomeAppToolbar');
    this.subToolbar.addControl(toolbarButtonShowDockingPanel);

    viewer.toolbar.addControl(this.subToolbar);
};

MyAwesomeExtension.prototype.unload = function () {
    this.viewer.toolbar.removeControl(this.subToolbar);
    return true;
};

Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension('MyAwesomeExtension', MyAwesomeExtension);
```

MyAwesomePanel:

```
// *******************************************
// My Awesome (Docking) Panel
// *******************************************
function MyAwesomePanel(viewer, container, id, title, options) {
    this.viewer = viewer;
    Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DockingPanel.call(this, container, id, title, options);

    // the style of the docking panel
    // use this built-in style to support Themes on Viewer 4+
    this.container.classList.add('docking-panel-container-solid-color-a');
    this.container.style.top = "10px";
    this.container.style.left = "10px";
    this.container.style.width = "auto";
    this.container.style.height = "auto";
    this.container.style.resize = "auto";

    // this is where we should place the content of our panel
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.margin = '20px';
    div.innerText = "My content here";
    this.container.appendChild(div);
    // and may also append child elements...

}
MyAwesomePanel.prototype = Object.create(Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DockingPanel.prototype);
MyAwesomePanel.prototype.constructor = MyAwesomePanel;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are missing the CSS for the Buttons and also the reference to the JS files pertaining to the extensions in your HTML file.

```
<script src="your_folder/MyExtensionFileName.js"></script>
```

http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/viewer/extensions/selection?id=toolbar-css 
Check this for the CSS of your extension buttons.

Comment: See line 10 of index.html for the script code, and I have included that css in my main.css, still getting the same issue.

Comment: I would move that to be read before the ForgeViewer.js, and also get rid of the first "/" and make it only js/MyAwesomeExtension.js you might be targeting the wrong location.

Comment: This worked, then I came across the issue that I hadn't set the index.html as the start up file (I can't believe it myself) but it works now, thank you so much for your help Jaime!