# Forge Basic Skeleton Example Toolbar not populating

Tags: asp.net, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I have already came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52335543/autodesk-forge-extension) that has a very similar problem.

My issue is that after making sure that all my links are accurate and spelled correctly I still cannot figure out why the button is not appearing. I also added a custom `img/icon.png` that is 24x24px.

Below is my `index.html`, `ForgeViewr.js`, `MyAwesomeExtension.js`, and `main.css`

Thank you for the help!

[Here is a screenshot of the current toolbars that appear when I build the project as is.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHEqL.png)

**index**

```
<head>
    <title>Autodesk Forge Tutorial</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!-- Common packages: jQuery, Bootstrap, jsTree -->
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />
    <!-- Autodesk Forge Viewer files -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/style.min.css?v=v6.0" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=v6.0"></script>
    <!-- this project files -->
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/MyAwesomeExtension.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ForgeTree.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ForgeViewer.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Fixed navbar by Bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/ -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav left">
        <li>
          <a href="http://developer.autodesk.com" target="_blank">
            <img alt="Autodesk Forge" src="//developer.static.autodesk.com/images/logo_forge-2-line.png" height="20">
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- End of navbar -->
  <div class="container-fluid fill">
    <div class="row fill">
      <div class="col-sm-3 fill">
        <div class="panel panel-default fill">
          <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="tooltip">
            Buckets &amp; Objects
            <span id="refreshBuckets" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" style="cursor: pointer"></span>
            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info" style="float: right" id="showFormCreateBucket" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createBucketModal">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span> New bucket
            </button>
          </div>
          <div id="appBuckets">
            tree here
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 fill">
        <div id="forgeViewer"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <form id="uploadFile" method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="hiddenUploadField" type="file" name="theFile" style="visibility:hidden" />
  </form>
  <!-- Modal Create Bucket -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="createBucketModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Cancel">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Create new bucket</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <input type="text" id="newBucketKey" class="form-control"> For demonstration purpouses, objects (files) 
          are NOT automatically translated. After you upload, right click on
          the object and select "Translate".
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="createNewBucket">Go ahead, create the bucket</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**ForgeViewer**

```
var viewerApp;

function launchViewer(urn) {
  var options = {
    env: 'AutodeskProduction',
    getAccessToken: getForgeToken
  };
  var documentId = 'urn:' + urn;
  Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function onInitialized() {
    viewerApp = new Autodesk.Viewing.ViewingApplication('forgeViewer');
    viewerApp.registerViewer(viewerApp.k3D, Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D, { extensions: ['MyAwesomeExtension'] });
    viewerApp.loadDocument(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
  });
}

function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {
  // We could still make use of Document.getSubItemsWithProperties()
  // However, when using a ViewingApplication, we have access to the **bubble** attribute,
  // which references the root node of a graph that wraps each object from the Manifest JSON.
  var viewables = viewerApp.bubble.search({ 'type': 'geometry' });
  if (viewables.length === 0) {
    console.error('Document contains no viewables.');
    return;
  }

  // Choose any of the avialble viewables
  viewerApp.selectItem(viewables[0].data, onItemLoadSuccess, onItemLoadFail);
}

function onDocumentLoadFailure(viewerErrorCode) {
  console.error('onDocumentLoadFailure() - errorCode:' + viewerErrorCode);
}

function onItemLoadSuccess(viewer, item) {
  // item loaded, any custom action?
}

function onItemLoadFail(errorCode) {
  console.error('onItemLoadFail() - errorCode:' + errorCode);
}

function getForgeToken(callback) {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/api/forge/oauth/token',
    success: function (res) {
      callback(res.access_token, res.expires_in)
    }
  });
}
```

**MyAwesomeExtension**

```
myawesomeextension

// *******************************************
// My Awesome Extension
// *******************************************
function MyAwesomeExtension(viewer, options) {
    Autodesk.Viewing.Extension.call(this, viewer, options);
}

MyAwesomeExtension.prototype = Object.create(Autodesk.Viewing.Extension.prototype);
MyAwesomeExtension.prototype.constructor = MyAwesomeExtension;

MyAwesomeExtension.prototype.load = function () {
    if (this.viewer.toolbar) {
        // Toolbar is already available, create the UI
        this.createUI();
    } else {
        // Toolbar hasn't been created yet, wait until we get notification of its creation
        this.onToolbarCreatedBinded = this.onToolbarCreated.bind(this);
        this.viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.TOOLBAR_CREATED_EVENT, this.onToolbarCreatedBinded);
    }
    return true;
};

MyAwesomeExtension.prototype.onToolbarCreated = function () {
    this.viewer.removeEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.TOOLBAR_CREATED_EVENT, this.onToolbarCreatedBinded);
    this.onToolbarCreatedBinded = null;
    this.createUI();
};

MyAwesomeExtension.prototype.createUI = function () {
    var _this = this;

    // prepare to execute the button action
    var myAwesomeToolbarButton = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Button('runMyAwesomeCode');
    myAwesomeToolbarButton.onClick = function (e) {

        // **********************
        //
        //
        // Execute an action here
        //
        //
        // **********************

        alert('I am an extension');

    };
    // myAwesomeToolbarButton CSS class should be defined on your .css file
    // you may include icons, below is a sample class:

    myAwesomeToolbarButton.addClass('myAwesomeToolbarButton');
    myAwesomeToolbarButton.setToolTip("My Awesome extension's tooltip");

    // SubToolbar
    this.subToolbar = (this.viewer.toolbar.getControl("MyAppToolbar") ?
        this.viewer.toolbar.getControl("MyAppToolbar") :
        new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.ControlGroup('MyAppToolbar'));
    this.subToolbar.addControl(myAwesomeToolbarButton);

    this.viewer.toolbar.addControl(this.subToolbar);
};

MyAwesomeExtension.prototype.unload = function () {
    this.viewer.toolbar.removeControl(this.subToolbar);
    return true;
};

Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension('MyAwesomeExtension', MyAwesomeExtension);
```

**main**

```
html, body{
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.fill{
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
}

body {
  padding-top: 60px; /* space for the top nav bar */
  margin-right: 30px;
}

#appBuckets {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 150px);
}

#forgeViewer {
  width: 100%;
}

.myAwesomeToolbarButton {
    background-image: url(img/icon.png);
    background-size: 24px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and register the extension with Viewer3D directly instead of ViewerApplication. I don't see anything out otherwise with your extension or Html/CSS and the below works well:

```
  var viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(myViewerDiv,{ extensions: ['MyAwesomeExtension'] });
```

Full code: https://jsfiddle.net/dukedhx/x80tmwcu/1/
[image]