# Autodesk Forge run via Heroku won't display the Dashboard Extension

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, heroku, autodesk-forge

I'm following the Autodesk Forge Step-by-step tutorial found at [learnforge.autodesk.io](https://learnforge.autodesk.io) and using the NodeJS option.

I'm currently in the final "Deployment" part and decided to use [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/). The Dashboard extension works very well when the app is run via local machine but doesn't display when run via Heroku.

Tried following [Autodesk Forge Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52335543/autodesk-forge-extension) topic but it didn't work for me.

**Edit:**
I did a checkup via Heroku CLI for the actual files on Heroku and the files and all other paths are exact the same as on local machine. By the way, I'm also using the free version of Heroku, so could it be the reason?

Chrome browser console shows the following errors:

- GET https://myApp.herokuapp.com/js/Dashboard/Dashboard.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
  myApp.herokuapp.com/:30
- GET https://myApp.herokuapp.com/js/Dashboard/DashboardPanel.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
  myApp.herokuapp.com/:32
- GET https://myApp.herokuapp.com/js/Dashboard/PanelPieChart.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
  myApp.herokuapp.com/:31
- GET https://myApp.herokuapp.com/js/Dashboard/PanelBarChart.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
  myApp.herokuapp.com/:29

My index.html is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>View Models - Autodesk Forge</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link
      rel="shortcut icon"
      href="https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewmodels/raw/master/img/favicon.ico"
    />
    <!-- Common packages: jQuery, Bootstrap, jsTree -->
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.7/jstree.min.js"></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.7/themes/default/style.min.css"
    />
    <!--Chart JS  packages-->
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.css"
    />
    <!-- Autodesk Forge Viewer files -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/style.min.css"
      type="text/css"
    />
    <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script>
    <!-- this project files -->
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/ForgeTree.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ForgeViewer.js"></script>
    <!-- Autodesk Forge Viewer HandleSelectionExtension -->
    <script src="js/HandleSelectionExtension.js"></script>
    <!-- Autodesk Forge Viewer Dashboard Extension -->
    <script src="js/Dashboard/Dashboard.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Dashboard/DashboardPanel.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Dashboard/PanelBarChart.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Dashboard/PanelPieChart.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Fixed navbar by Bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/ -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav left">
          <li>
            <a href="http://developer.autodesk.com" target="_blank">
              <img
                alt="Autodesk Forge"
                src="//developer.static.autodesk.com/images/logo_forge-2-line.png"
                height="20"
              />
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- End of navbar -->
    <div class="container-fluid fill">
      <div class="row fill">
        <div class="col-sm-4 fill">
          <div class="panel panel-default fill">
            <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="tooltip">
              Buckets &amp; Objects
              <span
                id="refreshBuckets"
                class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"
                style="cursor: pointer"
              ></span>
              <button
                class="btn btn-xs btn-info"
                style="float: right"
                id="showFormCreateBucket"
                data-toggle="modal"
                data-target="#createBucketModal"
              >
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span> New
                bucket
              </button>
            </div>
            <div id="appBuckets">tree here</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 fill">
          <div id="forgeViewer"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <form id="uploadFile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input
        id="hiddenUploadField"
        type="file"
        name="theFile"
        style="visibility: hidden"
      />
    </form>
    <!-- Modal Create Bucket -->
    <div
      class="modal fade"
      id="createBucketModal"
      tabindex="-1"
      role="dialog"
      aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
    >
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button
              type="button"
              class="close"
              data-dismiss="modal"
              aria-label="Cancel"
            >
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Create new bucket</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <input type="text" id="newBucketKey" class="form-control" /> For
            demonstration purposes, objects (files) are NOT automatically
            translated. After you upload, right click on the object and select
            "Translate". Bucket keys must be of the form [-_.a-z0-9]{3,128}
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
              Cancel
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="createNewBucket">
              Go ahead, create the bucket
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Oh, wizards of the codesmos, please heed my call for I need aid.

Comment: Deployment of the Node.js sample to Heroku should be pretty seamless, even when using the free tier. Are you deploying the sample app as is, or have you modified it in some way?

Comment: If you could share the code you're trying to deploy, that'd help us debug your issue, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it to work.

**It was just a "case sensitivity" issue.**

My real path was "js/**d**ashboard/" and it was referenced as "js/**D**ashboard/". It has to be the real case level. The local machine debug didn't care about this, but the server does.

I had followed the Learnforge step-by-step tutorial "to the letter" as in copied the already thought out codes. I guess this was some basic server-side knowledge that I had forgotten.

Thank you for reaching out to help!